# Add/Update parameter for a Context

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

In Dialogflow fulfillment I am trying to add or update parameters for a context.

```
let currentContext = agent.context.get('setupcall-followup');
console.log(agent.context.get('setupcall-followup').parameters); //1
currentContext.parameters.date = '2019-09-18T12:00:00-04:00';
currentContext.parameters.time = '2019-09-17T13:00:00-04:00';
currentContext.parameters['Test'] = 'Test';
console.log(agent.context.get('setupcall-followup').parameters); //2
agent.context.set(currentContext); //Seems to not be needed, since it is by reference
console.log(agent.context.get('setupcall-followup').parameters); //3, same as #2
```

By #2 & #3 the log shows that it was updated. 
But in the Diagnostic Info > Raw API Response, the outputContext information is still the original inputContext, before modification.

What I can do:

- Add a **new** context, with it's own parameters.

What I can't do

- Get a context & change a parameter

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way I finally got it to work.

Use a custom context & recreate it completely, every-time.
FYI Code below requires lodash for _.merge

```
function getSessionData() {
    if(agent.context.get('session_details')) {
        return agent.context.get('session_details').parameters.sessionDetails;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

function setSessionData(data) {
    if(agent.context.get('session_details')) {
        let session = agent.context.get('session_details').parameters.sessionDetails;  //Extract the data from the existing "session_details" context
        _.merge(session, data);   //Update our data
        let sessionContext = {    //Define the complete context object again
            name: "session_details",
            lifespan: 5,
            parameters: {
                sessionDetails: session
            }
        }
        agent.context.set(sessionContext);
    } else {
        let sessionContext = {    //Define the complete context object again
            name: "session_details",
            lifespan: 5,
            parameters: {
                sessionDetails: data
            }
        }
        agent.context.set(sessionContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help.

```
const parameters = {'param1':value, 'param2': value};
agent.context.set(context, 5, parameters); //here "5" is lifespan.
```

Tell me if it worked.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I tried it with this: const parameters = {'param1': 'value', 'param2': 'value'}; agent.context.set('Test', 5, parameters);

Comment: Correction. That does work, if I am trying to set a new context. What I am trying to do is manipulate a parameter (update) inside a current context.

Comment: If this is the case, you can get parameters from old context -> save parameters in variable -> delete old context -> create new context with same name -> add params from variable.

Comment: When 'deleteing', the context lifespan is set to 0. And removed for next round of conversation. (I tried)